# Tighter bound on time complexity of python code for replacing whitespaces

Tags: python, string, time-complexity

So i have this code with me which replaces every whitespace in the string with "%20". The code assumes that the changes are in place and that the string has sufficient space to handle more insertions. Also the true length of the string will also be given.

Here's the code.

```
def URLify(string, length):
    string = list(string)
    j = length - 1
    i = j - 1
    while i > 0:
        if string[i - 1] == " ":
            for k in range(j, i - 1, -1):
                string[k + 2] = string[k]

            string[i] = "2"
            string[i + 1] = "0"
            string[i - 1] = "%"
            j = j + 2

        i = i - 1

    return "".join(string)


string = "Mr John Smith       "
length = 13
print(URLify(string, length))
##Output:  Mr%20John%20Smith
```

I am trying to calculate a more tighter bound to its time complexity than O(n). Need advise on what will be the time complexity.

Comment: if you know the use of `.join()`, why don't you just do `"%20".join(string.split(" "))`? (Nevermind, that would put a lot of `%20`s at the end of the output but it's still a worth considering line)

Comment: Doesn't `str.replace(' ', r'%20')` work just as well? Unless it does something that's slower than `join()`

Comment: @Shinratensei you could add `.rstrip()` (and `.lstrip()`) if necessary.

Comment: right, `"%20".join(string.strip().split(" "))` would do it

Comment: Thanks everybody for the suggestion but i am trying to solve this in a language agnostic way.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity for removing white spaces cannot be reduced further than O(n). Although [shinra Tensei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625477/shinra-tensei) provided an easier approach.

```
    "%20".join(string.strip().split(" "))
```

This will do the job.

Comment: Please note that comments are transient and may get deleted for any reason. While it's right to give attribution to the person who first suggested it, I would recommend recreating the approach in your answer so that you can preserve it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up [roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799172/roganjosh)

Comment: My actual worry is that how does the inner loop in my original code impacts the overall time complexity ?

Comment: For every nested loop, you can roughly assume that your program's complexity is multiplied by n, so, roughly speaking, it should be O(n^2), but I tried your code and counted number of total loop iterations which came out to be 28.